# If the following $f(x, y)$ defines a metric, what do circles look like using this metric?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, circles

Define $f(x,y)$ on the infinite Euclidean plane as:
$$f(x,y) = \{1\ {\rm if}\  x\neq y;\ 0\ {\rm if}\ x=y\}$$

I know that f is a metric and any point is a distance of 1 away from any other point not equal to it. I'm trying to visualize what a circle would be. Would there even be a radius since the point of the center of a circle would still be a distance of 1 from any other point on the circle? I'm thinking that a circle would be all possible points in the plane... so it would take up the entire plane. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What you have is the "discrete metric."  A circle is not a useful construction to help you to visualize this metric.  All points are equally far apart (unless they are the same point).  I think of any set as a collection of dots.

Answer (score 4):

If you define a circle of radius $r$ to be the set of points at distance $r$ from some fixed centre point, then in that metric every circle has radius $1$, and there is one circle of radius $1$ for each point $p$. Specifically, the circle of radius $1$ centred at $p$ consists of all of the other points of the plane. Each point is the centre of one circle, that circle has radius $1$, and every other point of the plane lies on that circle.

As you can see, the notion of *circle* isn’t very informative here. It’s meaningful, but it doesn’t really tell you much about the space.